# Comparing 2 Columns in same table

Tags: mysql

I need to compare 2 columns in a table and give 3 things:

- **Count of rows checked** (Total Rows that were checked)
- **Count of rows matching** (Rows in which the 2 columns matched)
- **Count of rows different** (Rows in which the 2 columns differed)

I've been able to get just rows matching using a join on itself, but I'm unsure how to get the others all at once.  The importance of getting all of the information at the same time is because this is a very active table and the data changes with great frequency.

I cannot post the table schema as there is a lot of data in it that is irrelevant to this issue.  The columns in question are both `int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'`.  For purposes of this, I'll call them `mask` and `mask_alt`.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info on what you mean by "matching", "different" and "checked"?

Comment: can you please post the schema of your table?

Comment: @johntotetwoo I cannot, but I did add more details about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select
    count(*) as rows_checked,
    sum(col = col2) as rows_matching,
    sum(col != col2) as rows_different
from table
```

Note the elegant use of `sum(condition)`.
This works because in mysql `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`. Summing these counts the number of times the condition is `true`. It's much more elegant than `case when condition then 1 else 0 end`, which is the SQL equivalent of coding `if (condition) return true else return false;` instead of simply `return condition;`.

Comment: Trying this one out now.  I've limited it down to just the past day.  Unfortunately, some of the columns I have to limit upon aren't indexed, so this is causing a full table scan of about 300 M rows :S

Comment: Is there a way you can limit the rows initially using an indexed column, *then* run the above over that. For example, if you are confident the limit appears within the last week of data, first select the last week's worth of data as an inner aliased query, then query the result of that.

Comment: I take that back, a couple of the columns I was limiting on were indexed, however they didn't have a very high cardinality.  Of the 800M rows in this table, almost 400M had to be scanned.  Of those, there were 143 M matches.  And that's just results over the past 10 weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want to count the rows where `col1` is or is not equal to `col2`, you can use an aggregate `SUM()` coupled with `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN col = col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS matching,
  SUM(CASE WHEN col <> col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS non_matching
FROM table
```

It may be more efficient to get the total `COUNT(*)` in a subquery though, and use that value to subtract the matching to get the non-matching, if the above is not performant enough.

```
SELECT
  total,
  matching,
  total - matching AS non_matching
FROM
(
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN col = col2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS matching
  FROM table
) sumtbl
```